# Display New Mail Desktop Alert not working on Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have the settings correct - just to make sure:
- Tools | Options | Preferences Tab | Email Options | Advanced Email Options the Display a New Mail Alert is checked.

It doesn't work When I click Preview.

I also use rules for emails delivered in other folders than Inbox to display the alert and I have the same problem. However, the envelop is displayed in the tray.

I think the problem started since I upgraded to SP2, not sure ... (it worked fine until 1-2 months ago).

Is there an workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be that the alert is being displayed off-screen? If you're comfortable with editing the registry, you can navigate to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\DesktopAlerts
```

and set the "XOffset" and "YOffset" values to zero (or near-zero). If that doesn't help, you may also try to delete the "Corner" value if it exists.

Comment: Thanks! I've been playing with the XOffset and YOffset values before and it didn't help.
Deleting the "Corner" entry fixed the problem! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just curios, do you know how this happened, was it due to SP2 update?

Comment: I can neither confirm nor deny that SP2 would do something like this, but I believe a lot more people would have experienced the same problem if that were the case. Usually such incidents occur if you've been using a secondary monitor, and the application remembers the last window position even after you unplug the secondary monitor. If you've never used a secondary monitor, I have no clue as to why this happened :)

Comment: Yeap, I also used a second monitor, this might be it.

Comment: Thanks, addig `XOffset` and `YOffset` solved my problem. Using a second monitor...

Comment: Excellent!! If you don't have the Xoffset and Yoffset just create those entries, it will work like a charm! Thank you so much for this solution, have been looking for it for several months..